# I am trying to display an array of Int from Firebase but I keep getting an error and I am not sure why

Tags: arrays, firebase, list, swiftui, foreach

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<tables.count, id: \.self) { item in
        Text("Table \(tables[tableNumber ?? 0].items): \(tables[item].items.formatted())")
    }
}
```

I thought that this code would display the already gathered data from Firebase like this example, Table 6: Burger.
But instead I got this error:

> **Instance method 'appendInterpolation(_:formatter:)' requires that '[String]' inherit from 'NSObject'**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] about what debugging info is necessary. Also, `ForEach` should _not_ be used with indices. Use `Identifiable` data

Comment: "example, Table 6: Burger" has no link. You can [edit] to add a link.